# Como receber valor de SESSION em tempo real com AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

Bom, o que eu consegui até agora foi fazer com que, ao usuário clicar em algum dos botões de paginação (1, 2, 3...) o PHP guarde uma SESSION com o número da página correspondente.

Segue o código:

```
<!-- BOTÃO COM O NÚMERO DA PÁGINA -->    
<button onclick="mudaVar(<?php echo $i; ?>);">
    <?php echo $i; ?>
</button>

<!-- FUNÇÃO PARA GUARDAR SESSION PG -->
function mudaVar(valor) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'sessions.php?valor='+valor
    });
}

// GUARDA SESSION PG
if(isset($_GET['valor'])){
    $_SESSION['pg'] = $_GET['valor'];
}
```

Até aí tudo bem, só que o problema é que a SESSION não é alterada naquele momento, só quando eu atualizo a página.

Como corrigir isso?